# How to generate an alphanumeric sequence in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

Is it possible to generate an alphanumeric sequence in DB2?

I want to create an alphanumeric sequence which starts from 'AA' and ends with '99', as follows:

```
AA...AZ, A0...A9, BA...BZ, B0...B9, ... ZA...ZZ, 
Z0...Z9, 0A...0Z,   00...09, 1A...1Z, 10...19, ...9A...9Z, 90...99
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive query that iterates from 0 to 1295 and DIV & MOD functions to lookup the alpha characters:

```
WITH n(n,x) AS
(
SELECT 0,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT n+1,x FROM n WHERE n<1295
)
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(x, n/36 + 1,1) || SUBSTR(x, MOD(n,36) + 1,1) 
FROM n
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. I just tried the above SQL provided by you, only one row ('AB') is generated. What I am looking for is a SQL that can generate an alphanumeric sequence which starts from 'AA' and ends with '99' and there should be 36*36=1296 rows in total. Anyway, this is a good beginning, really appreciate your help. I am trying to make it work base on your SQL.

Comment: @JackChung  Rewritten with recursion

Comment: The new SQL provided by you works perfectly, now the result is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 has the [CREATE SEQUENCE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004201.html) statement to allow the creation of numeric sequences. There is functionality to obtain the current and the next value of defined sequences. Create a [SQL function](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html?pos=2) that, when invoked, obtains the next value from your sequence and translates it into your specific encoding.